# CommandArgument is returning null

Tags: c#, button, commandargument

I have a Button that i want to generate a soft delete with. Used an OnCommand with an Eval CommandArgument.

```
  <asp:Button ID="Button2" ValidationGroup="Delete" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnCommand="Button2_Command" 
            CommandArgument=<%# Eval("Product.Id") %> />
```

But the CommandArgument keeps returning null at the method behind.

```
protected void Button2_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        var Id = e.CommandArgument.ToString();

        TransactionCode.DeletePurchase();
    }
```

The table that gets the Id is part of a .dll DataContext. It works just fine with everything but at this case it keeps returning me null. I also have a class in the .dll witch contains the DeletePurchase() method. Should i add some property or smth to the class? Thank you!

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in the function to see if it is getting the parameters passed in correctly?

Comment: @Tim yes i put a breakpoint at the Initialization of the Button2_Command() Event and the var id remains the null cause the command arguments still is null, but i checked so many time the Eval putting the name of the table and the property i want to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command argument value should be within single quotes :

```
CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Product.Id") %>'
```

Comment: HI, thank you for the observation there, it missed me but i still got the problem.   `var Id = e.CommandArgument.ToString();` still remains null. 
If i want to get data from that table from the Eval should the tables be connected with a single foreing key, or should i add a field in the table Product as a nullable transaction code for the Eval to work?

Comment: I fixed the problem, it was a contextual one. Your answer helped me alot, thank you.